# Button could not be tapped - using UI Automation

Tags: iphone, ui-automation

I use UI Automation to test an iPhone app. My "Add" button cannot be tapped. Is there anything else that must be enabled to make this work?

Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().toolbar().buttons()[0] could not be tapped. I can see the button in the Elements trace: 
[image]

Automation Script:

```
var toolbar = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().toolbar();
    toolbar.buttons()[0].tap();
    toolbar.buttons()["Add"].tap();
```

(have tried both lines above)

Xcode:

```
- (void)configureToolbarItems {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                      target:self action:@selector(addNewTaskButtonPressed)];
    addButtonItem.accessibilityLabel=@"Add";

    (some other buttons here...)

    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           addButtonItem,flexibleSpace, helpBarButton, flexibleSpace, shoppingBarButton, nil] animated:YES];                    
}
```

Comment: For some reason the button will not click for a user either. Seems to be an iOS7 issue. This worked before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: MainWindow.xib - Enabled "Full Screen at Launch". Until this was checked, the app worked only for the smaller screen resolutions. Now it works for all resolutions. And in fact - the button could not be tapped in the real app. So UI Automation was right all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var navigationBar = app.navigationBar();
var editButton = navigationBar.leftButton();
editButton.tap();
```